# Creating a modal Dialog with Ruby/Tk

Tags: ruby, dialog, modal-dialog, tk-toolkit

I have the following code:

```
  dialogproc = proc {
    if (tree.focus_item)
      per = Person.get(tree.focus_item)
      dialog = persondialog(per, root)
      dialog.set_focus()
      dialog.grab()
      dialog.transient(root)
      per.save
    end
  }
```

In persondialog I create a TkToplevel. I want it to be modal in the way I'm used to it through Toolkits like Borlands OWL, where control is given to the dialog and person would be saved after the dialog is closed. In my example save is called at the same moment when the dialog is shown.

Except of that the dialog is pretty modal (you can interact with the window border, but that is no problem for me). I have made some wild tests with tkwait (pretty undocumented for ruby users) but without success. Either it didn't work at all or it came up with some strange tk error messages that did not point in a useful direction.

I'm not sure if I go in the right direction. I could probably solve my problem by giving a proc into the persondialog, that is called when the save button is called and if desired saves the person or does something else.

Or is inheriting a class from a TopLevel necessary?

How are your advices for a best solution. I want the dialog to only make changes to the model but not to the database. This should be done somehow independently. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set a grab on a window that's actually existing on the screen. Try waiting until after a `<Map>` or `<Expose>` event (only exposed to the script level in Tk 8.5 up) has been delivered to the window (or better yet a `<Visibility>` event, though they're only supported when rendering via X11).

This will require you to split your code into several pieces, with some of it going in an event handler; if you want the code to behave like a synchronous call (from the perspective of “outside”) then you need to use some sort of wait-for-event mechanism. That's what tkwait does, but I don't know enough about Ruby's coupling to Tk to offer advice on how to make that work. If you can have your API work by through invoking a callback once the response comes from your dialog, that's much easier to integrate as that's how Tk works internally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to be modal
>
> control is given to the dialog[,] and person would be saved after the dialog is closed

It's possible that, if the modal dialog is extremely simple, you could use
[`Tk.messageBox`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/messageBox.htm).
Automatically this is a modal window, and acquires control. You could also invoke a whole series of `Tk.messageBox`es, and thus obtain a person's answers to a long list of yes-or-no questions. For information, go to
[Standard Dialogs](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs)
(in the TkDocs tutorial) and scroll to section Alert and Confirmation Dialogs.

If you need a modal window that is more general,
[TkToplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/toplevel.htm)
is indeed the right approach. See section
[Creating and Destroying Windows](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#createdestroy)
in the tutorial.

> I could probably solve my problem by giving a proc into the persondialog, that is called when the save button is called[,] and if desired saves the person or does something else

Exactly right.

> I have made some wild tests with tkwait

Of course, `tkwait` involves threads. Instead, why not just let people click the non-modal window if they want to?